# Spark Scala Make some mathematical operations over columns in two dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

We have two dataframes :

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | height | weight |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |    12  |      5 |
|  2 |      8 |      7 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

and the other :

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | Area | Area_2 |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |      |        |
|  2 |      |        |
+----+------+--------+
```

I need join  the two dataframes by the id and de result in the second df must be something like this :

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id |  Area   | Area_2 |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | (12*5)  | (12+5) |
|  2 | (8*7)   | (8+7)  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

(where Area and Area_2 need to have de result of the operation between height and weight from the other DF , and joined by id)

Comment: so what will be the use of df 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  val df1 = Seq((1, 12, 5), (2,8,7)).toDF("id", "height", "weight")
  val df2 = Seq((1),(2)).toDF("id") // drop area and area2 columns from this df
  val df3 = df1.withColumn("area", col("height")* col("weight")).withColumn("area2", col("height") + col("weight"))
  val finaldf = df2.join(df3, Seq("id"))

  scala> finaldf.show
  +---+------+------+----+-----+
  | id|height|weight|area|area2|
  +---+------+------+----+-----+
  |  1|    12|     5|  60|   17|
  |  2|     8|     7|  56|   15|
  +---+------+------+----+-----+
```